# Update rows in one table depending on a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables in different databases in SQL Server.

**database1.table_A**

```
id   |    name    | present   |
-----|------------|-----------|
1    |    jon     |   1       |
2    |    ham     |   0       |
3    |    sam     |   1       |
7    |    tom     |   1       |
```

**database2.table_B**

```
absentid  |
----------|
  1       |
  5       |
  7       |
```

For every `id` value present in **table_B**, I want the value of `present` in **table_A** to be `0`. So, my **final result** should look like -

```
id   |    name    | present   |
-----|------------|-----------|
1    |    jon     |   0       |
2    |    ham     |   0       |
3    |    sam     |   1       |
7    |    tom     |   0       |
```

I want to confirm if the following query I wrote is correct or if there are any better ways to do this:

```
update database1.table_A
set present=0
FROM database1.table_A t1
 inner join
   database2.table_B t2
ON t1.id = t2.absentid;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set `present = 1` if they are *not* in the table, then you would use `left join`:

```
update t1
set present = (case when t2.absentid is null then 1 else 0 end)
from database1.table_A t1 left join
     database2.table_B t2
     on t1.id = t2.absentid;
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep the value in that case, your version is fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I don't really want to set `present=1` if the `id` is not present in `table_B`. So should I go with my version? Just wanted to make sure it's the best and right way to do what I want

Comment: @kev . . . Your version is fine for that.